# How do I implement Firebase authentication with local state with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was following [using-firebaseauth-with-local-state](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react#using-firebaseauth-with-local-state) to implement authentication in my react app but I am using functional components and hooks. How am I supposed to implement the `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()`?

Here is the code I have in the `Login.jsx` component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import firebase from "firebase";


// Configure Firebase.
const config = {
  apiKey: "myapikey",
  authDomain: "mydomain.firebaseapp.com"
  // ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Configure FirebaseUI.
const uiConfig = {
  // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
  signInFlow: "popup",
  // Redirect to /signedIn after sign in is successful. Alternatively you can provide a callbacks.signInSuccess function.
  signInSuccessUrl: "/",
  // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  callbacks: {
    // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false
  }
};

export default function Login() {
  const [signedIn, setSignIn]= useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
    const unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        (user) => setSignIn({isSignedIn: !!user})
    );
    unregisterAuthObserver();
    console.log("Sdd")
    };
  })

  if (!signedIn) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <p>Please sign-in:</p>
        <StyledFirebaseAuth
          uiConfig={uiConfig}
          firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <p>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}! You are now signed-in!</p>
      <a onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? If you have any concerns or if it didn't worked for you please let me know. If you found the answer useful, then please consider accepting it. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have not tried it out. But I am going to do so now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How am I supposed to implement the `componentDidMount()` and
>   `componentWillUnmount()`?

Use `useEffect` with an empty array to emulate a `componentDidMount`; then return a function from that same `useEffect` to emulate `componentWillUnmount`.

In your code, `useEffect` return a function, so that means that this function will execute when the component will get unmounted, so your `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` will get hooked when you'll done with the `Login` component.

To make a proper hook, set `useEffect` like this:

```jsx
useEffect(() => {

  const unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged(
      (user) => setSignIn({isSignedIn: !!user})
    );

  // Now you either return just unregisterAuthObserver
  // which will be called when the component is unmounted
  return unregisterAuthObserver;

  // or you create a function if you want more login when the component is unmounted
  // return () => {
  //   unregisterAuthObserver();
  //   console.log("Sdd");
  // }

}, []); // Important, pass an empty array so to execute useEffect hook only once
```